# The handlebar helper function did not working?

Tags: node.js, regex, express

I'm doing this seeing videos the fn keyword or function whatever it is doesn't shows up for me.
i tried too many time also didn't getting proper reference in document if shows the problem where i doing mistake it will be very helpful for me..

### edit.handlebars

```
{{#select post.status}}
            <option value="public">Public</option>
            <option value="private">Private</option>
            <option value="draft">Draft</option>
    {{/select}}
```

Here is my handlebar_helper.js file

### handlebar_helper.js

```
    module.exports = (Handlebars)=>{
  Handlebars.registerHelper('select', function(selected, options) {
    return options.fn(this).replace(new RegExp('value = \"'+ selected + '\"'), '$&selected="selected"');
  });

};
```

the Main file app.js including set view engine

### app.js

```
const {select} = require('./helpers/handlebars_helpers')

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'home', helpers: {select: select}}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

Comment: are you sure `options.fn` isn't undefined?

Answer (score 0):

From handlerbars documentation:

`Handlebars.registerHelper('select', function(options) {
  return options.fn(this);
});`

It looks like you have your arguments wrong in your helper function.

Comment: It shows error handlebars.registerHelper shows ':' expected. after changing it into colon  it shows this error (ReferenceError: registerHelper is not defined)

Comment: did i have to install any module for this handlebar or registerhelper i only installed express-handlebars module

Comment: #Bwaxxlo help me plz

Comment: Bwaxxlo i m made slighty changes  it shows error missing helper select

Comment: i asked question again here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53112601/missing-helper-select