# Missing helper "select"?

Tags: node.js, regex, express

I m trying to show the selected option from the mongodb. I've tried to many times to solve this problem from checking different sources. i got this error ( Error: Missing helper: "select")

here is my handlebar_helper.js file

```
module.exports = (Handlebars)=>{
  Handlebars.registerHelper('select', function(selected, options) {
    return options.fn(this).replace(new RegExp('value = \"'+ selected + '\"'), '$&selected="selected"');
  });

};
```

here is my main file app.js

```
const {select} = require('./helpers/handlebars_helpers');

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'home', helpers: {select: select}}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

here is edit.handlebars

```
{#select post.status}}
            <option value="public">Public</option>
            <option value="private">Private</option>
            <option value="draft">Draft</option>
    {{/select}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `registreHelper` if you are going to pass helper functions as arguments. Just export the function itself":

handlebar_helper.js:

```
module.exports = function(selected, options) {
    return options.fn(this).replace(new RegExp('value = \"'+ selected + '\"'),'$&selected="selected"');
}
```

everything else should work unchanged.

Of course, this makes the name of the helper file a bit weird. I'd rename it to `select_helper.js` - but that's just an opinion.

Comment: did i have to change something into edit.handlebars file inside option tag

Comment: I changed the name helpers:{selectOption : select} and also edit.handlebars and handlebar_helper.js now it shows selectOption is missing